# Can we reuse the Tridion search functionality in custom page?

Tags: 2013-sp1, custom-page

[image]
[image]

As per the business requirement, in Custom Page they want the search functionality based on different criteria selected(like Publication, select Component type (Schema))
 and also select different fields of that particular Component for filtering and after clicking on Run, the resulting filtered component will be displayed the same as Tridion view. When we right click the Component, that Component should have the same properties/options like versioning, open history.

Is the same result view (version, open, publishing, history etc..) possible? Also, how we can reuse the Tridion search functionality in a Custom Page.

Comment: Anyone has any idea about how to  reuse the exact look and feel of Tridion from  a Custom Page.

Answer (score 4):

I'll answer the second question first

> how we can reuse the Tridion search functionality in a Custom Page.

Take a look at Core Service, and `GetSearchResults` (and other related methods for retrieving the results of a search). For filtering take a look at `SearchQueryData` which is passed in the previous method.

As for the first question,

> Is the same result view (version, open, publishing, history etc..) possible

I'm not really sure whether you can reuse the exact look and feel of Tridion from within a Custom Page, I think not but I could be mistaken, someone with more experience with the UI can probably confirm this. What you **can** do is to build the same menu "manually" and implement the same functionality/buttons, again, using Core Service methods.

Comment: As my requirement is to search based on the metadata field of the component, so how to search using metadata filed in SearchQueryData? Any information will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that that level of granularity is possible.

Comment: Thanks Atila Sos for helpful information on this.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If you have sufficient information and consider the question answered, then please accept the answer so the question "becomes closed".